# Is there a way to inline delegate in C#?

Tags: c#, delegates, inline

Here's a simplified scenario that I'm dealing with. There are multiple methods with the looping structure.

```
for (int i=0; i<I; i++) {
    // Do something
    for (int j=0; j<J; j++) {
        // Do something
        for (int k=0; k<K; k++) {
            // Do something
            Update(a,b,c);
        }
    }
}
```

In one method, Update(a,b,c) is

```
a[i] += b[j] * c[k]
```

In another method, it is

```
b[j] += a[i] * c[k]
```

And yet in another method, it is

```
c[k] += a[i] * b[j]
```

At the moment, my code is duplicated everywhere. Is there a pattern in C# so that I don't duplicate code? I was tempted to use delegate but it seems that delegate would degrade the performance (which is critical in my case).

Is there a way to write a macro or an inline delegate function for such scenario?

Comment: Can you explain what this code is? Or what the context is? It's hard to figure out how delegates fit ino this...

Comment: @l46kok: It is not. See the full text where this citation was cut out.

Comment: Are `I`, `J`, `K` always equal to the array lengths, or are they separate values?

Comment: I,J,K are separate values.

@l46kok: perf is absolutely critical for the problem that I'm dealing with and you can clearly see that Update is the bottleneck.

Comment: @zer0ne If that's the case, this is more likely array bounds checking killing you - any conversion to a delegate is only going to add more overhead, too - not less, as the delegate call will be (very slightly) more expensive than a standard method call.  Are the array types fixed and always the same type?

Comment: This smells like code where the performance hit of a delegate call isn't acceptable. But you should benchmark it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something like this?

```
void DoUpdates(Action<int, int, int> update)
{
  for (int i=0; i<I; i++) {
    // Do something
    for (int j=0; j<J; j++) {
      // Do something
      for (int k=0; k<K; k++) {
        // Do something
        update(i, j, k);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and then in the caller

```
DoUpdates((int i, int j, int k) => { a[i] += b[j] * c[k]; });
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks for beautiful scheme. I'm thinking of applying this scheme to my specific problem.

One early question: Action is a delegate. Will it have any performance effect? Will the compiler inline the action?

Comment: The answer to your first question is: get a stopwatch, run the code and you'll find out how fast it is. The answer to your second question is no.

Comment: It is indeed efficient, and I want to understand why (given that it's not inlined). 

There's no way that DoUpdates can understand what update is at compile time. However, could it be the case that everything is inlined at the caller's level? 

At the point of this writing, I haven't researched a good tool to read intermediate language yet.

Comment: @zer0ne: What justifies the implication that inlining code makes it faster? Inlining code can make it slower. Inlined code is larger, so it can cause extra page faults, and it can mess up register scheduling in some situations. It's not like its a guaranteed win. Code can be fast and not inlined.

Comment: @zer0ne: You can read IL with ILDASM, but of course IL doesn't run. There's no point in trying to understand performance at the IL level.

Answer (score 5):

```
void Update<T>(T[] x, T[] y, T[] z, int i, int j, int k)
{
    x[i] += y[j] * z[k];
}
```

Usage:

```
Update(a, b, c, i, j, k);
Update(b, a, c, j, i, k);
Update(c, a, b, k, i, j);
```

I see that `a` is always accessed by `i` (and so on - `b` by `j`, `c` by `k`). You can try to optimize the code using this fact.

Comment: I was about to say generics could help, but this illustrates my idea better.

Comment: This example doesn't work.  `+=` and `*` are not defined for type `T`

Comment: So now only one `Update` method is needed, and the caller sets the behaviour with parameters. Great, but if arrays `a`, `b`, `c` share the same type, does it need to be a generic method?

Comment: This would work because I know the type (float). Generics is not necessary but I can see that it is useful in other cases.

Comment: I didn't know underlying array type OP is using so decided to write it in a generic form. It even doesn't work as-is but let's say it's a pseudo-code just to illustrate the idea.

Answer (score 2):

If performance is critical you could avoid the method call in the inner loop, like this:

```
void Update(int[]x, int[]y, int[]z, int I, int J, int K)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < I; i++)
    {
        // Do something
        for (int j = 0; j < J; j++)
        {
            // Do something
            for (int k = 0; k < K; k++)
            {
                // Do something
                x[i] += y[j] * z[k];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the calling code:

```
Update(a, b, c, I, J, K);
Update(b, a, c, J, I, K);
Update(c, a, b, K, I, J);
```

Comment: Thanks. I probably simplified the problem too much. The loop order can't be changed, i.e. the order of "do something" actually matters.

Comment: Ah I was afraid of that. I guess you could try wrapping each "do something" in a lambda. This is unlikely to be pretty (because it would increase the parameter count for `Update` to 9), but may give you the speed you want.

Answer (score 0):

Likely you are implementing something like large number multiplication or other linear combination of vectors. The reason you would need the approach you described as *inline delegate* is quite probably because of the varying place to store the result during the calculation and also because the nested for-loops are hard coded. Thus I suggest to revise your code like following:

```
public void Update(int destinationIndex, int[][] arrays, int[] indices) {
    var product=1;

    for(var i=indices.Length; i-->0; )
        if(destinationIndex!=i)
            product*=arrays[i][indices[i]];

    arrays[destinationIndex][indices[destinationIndex]]+=product;
}

public void PerformUpdate(
    int destinationIndex, int[] counts, int[][] arrays, Action<int, int>[] actions,
    List<int> indices=null, int level=0
    ) {
    if(level==counts.Length)
        Update(destinationIndex, arrays, (indices??new List<int>()).ToArray());
    else
        for(int count=counts[level], i=0; i<count; i++) {
            if(null!=actions&&level<actions.Length)
                actions[level](i, count); // do something according to nesting level

            (indices=indices??new List<int>()).Add(i);
            PerformUpdate(destinationIndex, counts, arrays, actions, indices, 1+level);
            indices.RemoveAt(indices.Count-1);
        }
}
```

This code is implemented in a recursive manner. The `int[][] array` can be replace with a generic array as long as you are going to define the calculation of `operator *` and `operator +`, rather the methods name in `MutiplyScalar` and `AddScalar`.

So, we would not use a delegate of `Update` to control the destination. Instead, we just use the `destinationIndex` to accomplish that. Following is a test case:

```
int[] a=new[] { 1, 2 }, b=new[] { 3, 4, 5 }, c=new[] { 6 };
Action<int, int> m=(index, count) => Debug.Print("index={0}; count={1}", index, count);
PerformUpdate(2, new[] { a.Length, b.Length, c.Length }, new[] { a, b, c }, new[] { m, m, m });
```

We still have inline delegates there, which are called [`Lambda Expressions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) in c#. According to the original code you provided, there're `Do something`s between the nested for-loops. However, there is not much information we can found which is non-globally known to `Update`; the most significant difference we can see is the **iterating index and the ending number**, which are `i, I`, `j, J` and `k, K`. Thus we just take these as arguments to pass to the `Action<int, int>` for doing something, and they are variable for each level of for-loop.

The execution is much depended on the `indices`. It stores the iterating index of current for-loop and passed to next level of recursive call. Further if you passed the `arrays` with a count smaller than its `Length` in `indices`, it's treated as an array with the length of that count you passed to. **Don't pass a negative count, neither a larger one.** It can be lack of `Action<int, int>`, that would just mean *do nothing* instead of *do something*.

Answer (score 0):

This will probably inline it.

```
interface IFunc<T>
{
    void Invoke(ref T a, ref T b, ref T c);
}

void DoUpdates<TFunc>(TFunc update)
    where TFunc : IFunc<int>
{
    for (int i = 0; i < I; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < J; j++)
            for (int k = 0; k < K; k++)
                update.Invoke(ref i, ref j, ref k);
}
```